Driving Mosfets using NPN - PNP transistors in Ltspice
I sent the SPWM I produced to the transistor as seen in the diagram below. pwm frequency 10 kHz.
As seen in the 2nd picture, PWM-A works fine.
As seen in the 3rd picture, I shared the unzoomed version of the PWM-A/ signal. There are distortions at the bottom of the signal.
Additionally, this distortion appeared when I increased the pwm frequency to 10 kHz.
What is the reason for this disruption and what should I do?

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

Source: My own study

"As seen" -- I don't see anything: if the signals are supposed to be complementary, should you not confirm (by basic operation, testing with a PULSE will suffice, no need to do full PWM cycles with it), and zoom in at such a scale that the edges and relative timing are clearly visible, and any other possible issues (like runt pulses or indeterminate voltages)?

What is the use of U3?

Note that U3 output is "short circuited" to V7 through Q1s base.

The whole exercise may be interesting but ultimately pointless. All you need is a single comparator with push-pull output. One chip. There's plenty of them to choose from.
You absolutely must tell us what U1 and U3 are. I presume that U1 is a push-pull output comparator (since there's no pull-up), and U3 is a regular op-amp. Typical op-amps will do a very poor job of buffering PWM, so you don't want that. You also don't need a discrete inverter. Swap the comparator inputs to invert the output signal.
Here's the complete circuit you may wish to start with:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
TLV1872 is basically a "gate driver lite" and a comparator in one package. It is an excellent part. There are others of course, but that one is fairly foolproof.

I shared the unzoomed version of the PWM-A/ signal. There are distortions at the bottom of the signal.

If you looked at the zoomed version, you'll hopefully get some hints why it looks the way it looks. Hint: Q1 gets saturated and takes forever to turn off.  It's just not the way to do it, in spite of what a lot of silly tutorials imply. Saturated BJTs as gate drivers and switching mosfet gates do not (almost) ever go together.

Interesting closing comment; could you explain why your example of saturated MOSFET switches go together with MOSFET gates? (Would also be curious what recommended types, or general ratings, M1/M2 could be.)

@TimWilliams Fixed: I meant that saturated BJTs do a very poor job as gate drivers and should almost never be used in switching applications. They are just too slow.

Well, I wouldn't say "very poor". Typical low-Vce(sat) types are blazingly fast (edge rates in the 10s of ns), yet capable of amperes. But I would say they take more work to run properly; there's more to manage with the low "on" voltage and stored base charge. The kind of thing that's manageable in an IC (all the classic (80s era?) drivers are bipolar), but you wouldn't bother with at the board level (dozens of discrete components required).

Do class B amplifiers saturate @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica ? I suggested a class B amplifier in my response left in the link by winny above, but from my experience (in simulation), they were more than capable of providing edges quick enough to at least switch a buffer mosfet power stage. This is a typical output config of bipolar gate drivers which are still rather common as they don't have significant shoot through and are easy to run.
